# Trying to hash a password

Tags: c#, hash, sha1

**Note: I will not be using salts. Thanks for your advice though!**

I'm testing how to hash a password using SHA1 and can't seem to wrap my head around it. My database column is Password char(40) not null.

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Consumer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string password = "Mypassword";
            byte[] data password.tobytearray()???
            byte[] result;

            SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
            // This is one implementation of the abstract class SHA1.
            result = sha.ComputeHash(data);
            Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _Note: I will not be using salts_ ... **You _should_.**   Why aren't you?

Comment: and what's your question? Not a single question mark in your whole question.

Comment: I see three of them. Probably should remove those though, can't imagine it compiles :)

Comment: Also, you should use `SHA512`.

Comment: No, really, it's kind of silly to use SHA-1, and then NOT use a salt.

Comment: @SLaks: Why not just go to PBKDF2? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: @SLaks: Before following the PBKDF2 advice, you might want to look at the related discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552464/how-can-i-vendorize-bcrypt-in-a-php-application-and-should-i/

Comment: Use both a salt, and a slow hash. Such as PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt. PBKDF2 is easiest in .net, since it's built into .net in the Rfc2898DeriveBytes class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to convert a `string` into a `byte[]`.  This is done by using one of the `Encoding` classes.

```
byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);
```

I'm not sure which is most appropriate for your scenario but I would use `Unicode` unless I had a specific reason to do otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

To convert a string to a `Byte[]`, use the `Encoding` class.

Also, `result` is a `Byte[]`, which doesn't override `ToString()`.

To get a string representation of the byte array, you can call `BitConverter.ToString` or `Convert.ToBase64String`.
In a database, you should store the raw byte array directly.

Answer (score 0):

So your correct program would be something like

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string password = "Mypassword";
        byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);
        //or byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
        byte[] result;

        SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        // This is one implementation of the abstract class SHA1.
        result = sha.ComputeHash(data);
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(result));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: I strongly recommend using UTF8 or UTF16 encoding, not ASCII. And of course SHA-1 is too fast.